# What is the equivalent of torch.nn.functional.grid_sample in Tensorflow / Numpy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and have been trying to convert some code. Can't find this particular functionality. Does it exist in tensorflow?

Comment: Not sure how feasible this is but do you need a solution for both 2D and 3D cases or only one of them? And also do you need the padding feature?

Comment: I implemented `interpn()` in tensorflow, which essentially does this. I hope this is useful to you: https://github.com/adalca/neuron/blob/master/neuron/utils.py . 

See also `transform()` and `SpatialTransformer` in `layers.py`, which might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think there is anything like that provided in TensorFlow. Here is a possible implementation for the 2D case (I have not considered padding, but the code should behave like the `border` mode). Note that, unlike the PyTorch version, I am assuming the input dimension order is `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` (as is common in TensorFlow).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def grid_sample_2d(inp, grid):
    in_shape = tf.shape(inp)
    in_h = in_shape[1]
    in_w = in_shape[2]

    # Find interpolation sides
    i, j = grid[..., 0], grid[..., 1]
    i = tf.cast(in_h - 1, grid.dtype) * (i + 1) / 2
    j = tf.cast(in_w - 1, grid.dtype) * (j + 1) / 2
    i_1 = tf.maximum(tf.cast(tf.floor(i), tf.int32), 0)
    i_2 = tf.minimum(i_1 + 1, in_h - 1)
    j_1 = tf.maximum(tf.cast(tf.floor(j), tf.int32), 0)
    j_2 = tf.minimum(j_1 + 1, in_w - 1)

    # Gather pixel values
    n_idx = tf.tile(tf.range(in_shape[0])[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], tf.concat([[1], tf.shape(i)[1:]], axis=0))
    q_11 = tf.gather_nd(inp, tf.stack([n_idx, i_1, j_1], axis=-1))
    q_12 = tf.gather_nd(inp, tf.stack([n_idx, i_1, j_2], axis=-1))
    q_21 = tf.gather_nd(inp, tf.stack([n_idx, i_2, j_1], axis=-1))
    q_22 = tf.gather_nd(inp, tf.stack([n_idx, i_2, j_2], axis=-1))

    # Interpolation coefficients
    di = tf.cast(i, inp.dtype) - tf.cast(i_1, inp.dtype)
    di = tf.expand_dims(di, -1)
    dj = tf.cast(j, inp.dtype) - tf.cast(j_1, inp.dtype)
    dj = tf.expand_dims(dj, -1)

    # Compute interpolations
    q_i1 = q_11 * (1 - di) + q_21 * di
    q_i2 = q_12 * (1 - di) + q_22 * di
    q_ij = q_i1 * (1 - dj) + q_i2 * dj

    return q_ij

# Test it
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, None])
grid = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 2])
res = grid_sample_2d(inp, grid)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Make test image
    im_grid_i, im_grid_j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(6), np.arange(10), indexing='ij')
    im = im_grid_i + im_grid_j
    im = im / im.max()
    im = np.stack([im] * 3, axis=-1)
    # Test grid 1: complete image
    grid1 = np.stack(np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 15), np.linspace(-1, 1, 18), indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
    # Test grid 2: lower right corner
    grid2 = np.stack(np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 15), np.linspace(.5, 1, 18), indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
    # Run
    res1, res2 = sess.run(res, feed_dict={inp: [im, im], grid: [grid1, grid2]})
    # Plot image and sampled grids
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(res1)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(res2)
```

Here are the resulting images, first the input:

[image: Input image]

First grid result, which is the first image but with different shape:

[image: First grid result]

Second grid result, which spans a region in the lower right corner:

[image: Second grid result]

Comment: your solution didn't work for me. but [this](https://github.com/kevinzakka/spatial-transformer-network/blob/master/stn/transformer.py#L159) worked. i think it's because the interpolation part at the end is wrong

Comment: I upvoted the above comment because the code in the link provided above worked for me. I haven't checked the code provided in the answer. Please don't mistake my upvote of the above comment as "code in answer not working".

Comment: @Khan not really clear what is the input of the bilinear_sampler.

Comment: Ok, it seems that @Khan's suggested function provides the same result as the numpy's grid_sample. The input for the tf version is (b, h, w) for x and y.