# Implement pytorch's Grid_sample using numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pytorch

My code right now works using the affine_grid and grid_sample from PyTorch. However, I need to change the implementation so it doesn't use PyTorch anymore.
Right now, I have the function **apply_tmfs()** that applies affine_grid and grid_sample to a "tensorized" image.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import Tensor
import torch

TensorImageSize = (int,int,int)
FloatTensor = torch.FloatTensor

class FlowField():
    def __init__(self, size: (int, int), flow: Tensor):
        self.size = size
        self.flow = flow

def _grid_sample(x:Tensor, coords:FlowField, mode:str='bilinear', padding_mode:str='reflection')->Tensor:
    coords = coords.flow.permute(0, 3, 1, 2).contiguous().permute(0, 2, 3, 1) # optimize layout for grid_sample
    if mode=='bilinear': # hack to get smoother downwards resampling
        mn,mx = coords.min(),coords.max()
        # max amount we're affine zooming by (>1 means zooming in)
        z = 1/(mx-mn).item()*2
        # amount we're resizing by, with 100% extra margin
        d = min(x.shape[1]/coords.shape[1], x.shape[2]/coords.shape[2])/2
        # If we're resizing up by >200%, and we're zooming less than that, interpolate first
        if d>1 and d>z: x = F.interpolate(x[None], scale_factor=1/d, mode='area')[0]
    return F.grid_sample(x[None], coords, mode=mode, padding_mode=padding_mode)[0]


def _affine_grid(size:TensorImageSize)->FlowField:
    size = ((1,)+size)
    N, C, H, W = size
    grid = FloatTensor(N, H, W, 2)
    linear_points = torch.linspace(-1, 1, W) if W > 1 else Tensor([-1])
    grid[:, :, :, 0] = torch.ger(torch.ones(H), linear_points).expand_as(grid[:, :, :, 0])
    linear_points = torch.linspace(-1, 1, H) if H > 1 else Tensor([-1])
    grid[:, :, :, 1] = torch.ger(linear_points, torch.ones(W)).expand_as(grid[:, :, :, 1])
    return FlowField(size[2:], grid)

def apply_tfms(img: Tensor , size: int = None, padding_mode: str = 'reflection',
               mode: str = 'bilinear') -> Tensor:
    if not (size) or size is None: return img
    crop_target = (size,size)
    flow = _affine_grid((img.shape[0],) + crop_target)
    if flow is not None:
        img = _grid_sample(img,flow, padding_mode=padding_mode, mode=mode)
    return img
```

Using numpy arrays instead of tensors worked to implement an _affine_grid using numpy:

```
def _affine_grid_numpy(size: TensorImageSize) -> FlowFieldNumpy:
    size = ((1,) + size)
    N, C, H, W = size
    grid = np.ndarray((N, H, W, 2))
    linear_points = np.linspace(-1, 1, W) if W > 1 else np.array([-1])
    grid[:, :, :, 0] = np.outer(np.ones(H), linear_points)
    linear_points = np.linspace(-1, 1, H) if H > 1 else np.array([-1])
    grid[:, :, :, 1] = np.outer(linear_points, np.ones(W))
    return FlowFieldNumpy(size[2:], grid)
```

But I have no idea how to implement **grid_sample** using Numpy. grid_sample is a built in function in C++.

Things I've considered:

1. I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888146/what-is-the-equivalent-of-torch-nn-functional-grid-sample-in-tensorflow-numpy), but uses TensorFlow and I'm not interested in using it.
2. In [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574143/sampling-numpy-array-with-float-indices-similar-to-pytorch-grid-sample), it is recommended to use OpenCV.remap() or scipy.interp2d. I'm also not interested in these two libraries.
3. Using another library other than OpenCV or Tensorflow.
4. I've considered translating to Python [the built in C++ grid_sampler function](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/native/GridSampler.cpp). That must be super difficult.

**Is there any way to implement grid_sample, but only using numpy instead of PyTorch?**